# Register a shutdown hook in Spring on restart of respective Kubernetes pod

Tags: spring

I have deployed my spring application via kubernetes.Multiple instances(pods) are running. I do use postgres db tables to log process input data and its state(Taking lock on some resoure ). Now it may happen that i will restart my application via restarting of K8s pods.
Is there a way that while restarting pods, i can do some shutdown hook in my application code to release my resources ?

Answer (score 1):

Before terminating pod SIGTERM signal will be sent to each container. You might handle signal using `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...);`. Application must handle SIGTERM within graceful period which is 30 seconds by default. Graceful period might be overridden in deployment spec:

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

Comment: Many Thanks Alexander Matyushentsev . Hope it will work